# Multisites login from main site to other site, drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, multi-sites

i have multisites installed single code and database, and 1 user table.

- users are classified as different types,
- and user get register from site1 or site2

i need to do is if user has type of site2. and if he is trying to login to mysite.com, user type is checked and redirect to specific site and login the user to that site.